# Welcome Email Going to Spam

Tags: email, email-verification

The user sign up welcome email is going directly to spam, Gmail says `this email may not have been sent by ****@gmail.com`

Would setting up a domain specific email address and changing the site owner email to `***@thedomain.com` help keep these messages from going into spam folders?

Comment: Don't get why you even ask, obviously the email is not sent by the user and is easy for google to know that when you use gmail.

Comment: obviously its not sent by gmail, youre right. I ask because I need a solution, and the email to not go to spam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add SPF record to your DNS so emails from your server IP are classified as legitimate

Edit. 
Do the above with what you said. 
"Would setting up a domain specific email address and changing the site owner email to ***@thedomain.com help keep these messages from going into spam folders?"

This will be fine as it will be the smtp server on your Web server which is sending the emails and hence will now get through spam checks

Comment: You can't add SPF for gmail.com on your site

Comment: Just updated answer